# How to change texture of all objects at the same time?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an object that has been divided into 3 parts and joined by a 'Plain Axes'. 
How do I change the texture of the 3 parts of the object at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the same materials on those parts if they are just using the same texture. have them UV unwrapped uniformly so they will have the same amount and look of the texture as you adjust the material.